# Confusion about motion and direction of resultant force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

When a ball is thrown upwards and there is no air resistance, the resultant force while going up is downwards, so why is the ball moving upwards? Could someone please clear my confusion? Is it because the force on a moving object changes the speed, not the direction?

Comment: After you give the ball its initial upward velocity, how many forces are acting on it and in what direction?

Comment: only weight is acting on it

Comment: So then the "resultant/net" force is just the weight. If instead you were driving the ball at a constant acceleration (by have a big blow drier or something) then there'd be an upward force competing against gravity But in the situation you've described, you've merely given a ball an initial velocity and let it act under Earth's gravity

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are confusing velocity and acceleration. The force is proportional to the acceleration, not the velocity. In the case of a projectile like your ball, the acceleration is at all times downward.

If there is no force there is no acceleration and the object moves in a straight line at constant speed. If there is acceleration (that is not in line with the velocity) then the object’s velocity will curve and the path will no longer be a straight line but will curve. The direction of the acceleration is the direction the path is curving towards.

In the case of a projectile the path is a parabola which is always curving downwards. So the acceleration is at all times downward, even when the velocity is upward.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's first law: an object continues in motion unless a force acts upon it.

Newton's second law: $F=MA$, i.e. force = mass times acceleration. We may rewrite this as:
$A = F/M$

Thus, the object is *accelerated* downwards by gravity.

But it does not all happen at once, the deceleration takes time. This is because $M$ is also the *inertial mass* of the ball.

Meanwhile, thanks to Newton's first law, the ball continues upwards, albeit slower and slower.

Answer (score 1):

Tipically, one talks about the resultan of forces when there are more than one. If you consider your ball going upward, the only force acting on it is the weight force $\vec{P}$, due to the earth gravitational attraction (supposed to be uniform for sufficiently low heights). The same force $\vec{P}$ acts on the ball even if it is standing still on ground.

The ball is going upward because at some time ($t=0$) someone/something gave it an initial velocity $\vec{v}$ which was upward. Suppose you throw the ball upward. While it is in your hand you apply to the ball a force through your arm, that is you change its velocity from 0 to its final values. By changing velocity means that you're accelerating the ball, and according to Newton's law your applying a force $\vec{F}$. Obviously, during the movement of your arm, $\vec{P}$ is always acitng on the ball. When you release the ball from your hand, you're now applying no force to the ball, and only $\vec{P}$ remains.

Now the effect of $\vec{P}$ it that of decelerating you ball as it goes up. Decelerating means the the velocity of your ball is decreasing untill it is zero at the maximum height. Now $\vec{P}$ acts to increasing the velocity of your ball in the opposite direction, i.e. downward.

As a last remark, keep in mind that force changes the velocity $\vec{v}$ and not necessarily the speed $v = |\vec{v}|$. Velocity is a vectorial quantity so acceleration can change the direction of $\vec{v}$ without changing the speed $v$ like in the uniform rotational motion.

Answer (score 0):

Force is proportional to acceleration (as Dale said in an earlier answer) and acceleration is the change in velocity with respect to time. The force of gravity is always downward. The force of gravity changes the velocity of the ball; in this case gravity decreases the upward velocity of the ball from its initial value to eventually zero, but during this time the ball has travelled upwards due to its (ever decreasing) upwards velocity.  Once the ball velocity is zero, gravity continues to change the velocity; gravity pulls the ball down increasing its downward velocity.